# Redux. How to run several sagas in sagaMiddleWare.run([ f1*(), f2*(), f3*() ]) with redux-saga?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I need the solution to start several sagas in different time points. I had created 3 different saga's and tryed to implement they to the `sagaMiddleWare.run()` like an array. But for now I gets an error - `runSaga(storeInterface, saga, ...args): saga argument must be a Generator function!`.

I understand why this error happens, but does not understand how to solve it?

Thank you!

```
sagaMiddleWare.run([watchSearchForCash, watchBootlegging, watchGraffiti])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make it work easly by combining all sagas in one wrapped, called (for example) `rootSaga`:

```
function * rootSaga() {
  yield [
    watchSearchForCash, 
    watchBootlegging, 
    watchGraffiti
  ]
}
```

and then implement your new saga holder `rootSaga` inside the `sagaMiddleWare.run(rootSaga)`

Thant's all the magic :)

Comment: yield [...effects] got deprecated. 

use yield all([  watchSearchForCash, 
    watchBootlegging, 
    watchGraffiti
  ]) insted.  dont forget to import {all} from 'redux-saga/effects';

Answer (score 0):

all watchers must have () because all are functions !

```
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects'
    import productSaga from './product/saga';
    function* rootSaga() {
        yield all([
            watcheProductSaga(),
            watcheUserSaga(),
        ])
      }
      export default rootSaga;
```